# Unlocking bootloader to change rom or firmware

Tags: custom-roms, bootloader, device-firmware, customization

My question is very easy: do I have to unlock the bootloader on every single phone to change its rom or its firmware, or someone need it and someone doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is also easy: some don't need it.

Most if not all AT&T/Verizon/Amazon devices are bootloader locked, yet some are popular enough that devs worked ways around it. A common-sight solution is called Safestrap.

- Safestrap for [AT&T Galaxy S4](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2448925)
- Safestrap for [AT&T Galaxy Note 3](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2572978)
- Safestrap for [Motorola RAZR](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2427125)
- Safestrap for [Amazon Kindle Fire HDX (3rd gen.)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2556677)

Do note that, with the lockdown measure becoming heavier over the years, there's no such solution I know of for recent devices. Even for older devices, Safestrap took a considerable long time to be developed/ported.